# Flutter web: SVG in Firefox

Tags: flutter, firefox, svg, flutter-layout, flutter-web

Does someone know a way to display a SVG in Firefox using Flutter.
I tried using [websafe_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/websafe_svg). It works great apart from Firefox, [the images are not visible](https://github.com/peiffer-innovations/websafe_svg/issues/7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) in addition with `--dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_USE_SKIA=true` behind `flutter run` seems to work for me.

Comment: Skia comes with issues right now though. Performance is great, but it has a few issues: Emojis, Box shadows look weird sometimes, Artifacts around dialog closing animation, Some drag action freezes my app (not sure what to make of that though). Also, it doesn't work in debug mode afaik.

Answer (score 0):

every thing depends on your SVG Format ... and I think best way is Changing Svg to a Right Format that you tested ...

I always use Adobe Illustrator for changing svgs Format. and below Format Working For Me on Both Android And Web... (Use Adobe Illustrator Action for saving Time )

[image]